# email and password is not shown in firebase console in sign in users option

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console

**Email** and **password** is not shown in ***FIREBASE CONSOLE*** in sign in users option.It is showing Registered Successfully Toast.It is showing nothing in `firebase` console after refreshing also.Below is my code.After long press, it is showing success. Please help if anyone has any idea.

Already given INTERNET permission in manifest file.
Please help

**Main Activity**

```
package in.nic.edudel.doe.firebaseauthentication;//package name

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name,password;
    Button btn,btn2;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    SignInButton signInButton;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        password = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                register();//function
            }
        });

        btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                login();//function

                return true;
            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                reset();
            }
        });

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });

    }

    private void signIn() {

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        // [START initialize_auth]

        // [END initialize_auth]
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w("MYSTEP", "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {


        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    private void reset() {

        mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(name.getText().toString().trim()).
                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Reset Email Sent !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email not found !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    private void login() {

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(name.getText().toString().trim(),password.getText().toString().trim()).
                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed !!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


    private void register() {

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(name.getText().toString().trim(),password.getText().toString().trim()).
                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered Successfully!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter valid data !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


    }
}
```

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.nic.edudel.doe.firebaseauthentication.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:text="Register" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:text="Reset Password" />

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, the entire authentication process using **[Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5)** and **[Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIRt9Ts0fRU&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=6)**.